# set TRANSFORMS argument in custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer, installation

Can I set the TRANSFORMS argument value in the custom action within the MSI ? If Yes, need to set the custom action being called at which stage ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Transforms can't be applied dynamically during an installation.  They have to be applied at the time the installation is started.  A custom bootstrapper (EXE) could use business logic to select a transform and apply it when starting the installation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed the mst files into the _Storages table inside the MSI, and windows will auto-detect the supported transforms for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368351(v=vs.85).aspx